# Stop docker compose volume from mounting in container after volume reference removed in file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, mount, volumes

I am currently running a custom built docker container using a docker compose file.
The docker compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    privileged: true
    image: custom_docker_image:17
    container_name: custom_docker_container
    command: '/usr/bin/supervisord'
    volumes:
       - /custom_docker_path/public:/public
       - /custom_docker_path/data/logs:/data/logs
       - /custom_docker_path/var/log:/var/log
       - /custom_docker_path/etc/nginx:/etc/nginx
       - /custom_docker_path/etc/supervisor:/etc/supervisor
       - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    ports:
       - '9202:9200'
```

The docker container runs services and processes which are kept alive using supervisor.
Everything ran as expected until I changed the volume mounting.

The file previously use to have the volumes as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    privileged: true
    image: custom_docker_image:17
    container_name: custom_docker_container
    command: '/usr/bin/supervisord'
    volumes:
       - /custom_docker_path/public/db:/public/db
       - /custom_docker_path/public/settings:/public/settings
       - /custom_docker_path/data/logs:/data/logs
       - /custom_docker_path/var/log:/var/log
       - /custom_docker_path/etc/nginx:/etc/nginx
       - /custom_docker_path/etc/supervisor:/etc/supervisor
       - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    ports:
       - '9202:9200'
```

Previously, only the db and settings folders in the public directory in the container where shared with the host machine. I then decided to share the entire public directory with the host machine.

The sharing was successful, except the **db** and **settings** folders were still being shared along with the entire public directory.

Running the **mount** command inside the container shows the following:

```
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /public type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /data/logs type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /public/db type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /public/settings type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /etc/supervisor type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /etc/letsencrypt type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /var/log type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/host_machine_mount root on /etc/nginx type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

From the above, **/public** gets mounted and so does **/public/db** and **/public/settings** even though they are not referenced in the new docker-compose file.

I elevated privileges in the container to manually remove the mounts after the container starts up and that works - but I can't keep entering the container and removing the two mount points.

I also tried removing the volumes outside docker and pruning but the two directories still mount inside the container on startup.

Tried running:

`docker-compose down -v`

`docker volume rm "volume_name"`

`docker volume prune`

Tried above commands while container was running, stopped and before and after restarts.

How do I stop these two directories from mounting inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `docker-compose down -v` to remove all containers AND volumes declared in your docker-compose.yml

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

> -v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`
> section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
> attached to containers.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the feedback. Have tried this and the volume gets removed from the list of docker volumes (docker volume ls) but when the container is started again the volume/mount gets re-created.

Comment: and you're sure there's no volume mounting `/custom_docker_path/public/` in your docker-compose file?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. The only volume mount is ```/custom_docker_path/public:/public```. The other mounts ```/custom_docker_path/public/db:/public/db``` and ```/custom_docker_path/public/settings:/public/settings``` were removed.

Comment: I did do quite a few docker commits to the image before changing the mount from /public/db and /public/settings to /public. Could those commits be preventing the image from dropping the /public/db and /public/settings mounts?

Comment: Does your Dockerfile used to create your custom image have a VOLUME that mounts to /public/db and /public/settings? I don't think docker commit should affect volumes at all.

Comment: Ah, I think this might be a misstep on my end that requires further investigation. The docker build I am using does not have a Dockerfile but runs directly through docker-compose which could possibly be the issue.